# problems moving a game sprite angle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a game sprite that I want to move verticaly, and normally this would be easy with `this.x += number`, exept for the fact that the x/y of the sprite are relitive to its angle. this can be kinda confusing so I have a example here.
[image]

in other cases where the picture will not load of something else i have a link
[examplepicture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-)

it can get kinda long do here is the basic code

```
this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
      if (type == "image") {
          
          
ctx.save();
       ctx.translate(300, 200);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y)
       
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
                this.width / -2, 
                this.height/ -2,
                this.width, this.height);
ctx.restore(); 
        
        
            }else {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        
        ctx.restore();
        
      }
    }



function framethingupdate() {
gamething.update();
}
```

due to certen issues i am unable to run or provide a demo, however if the full code is needed you can find it her: [full code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VUvqZ4sFNfEyXxsJ3zSXvbmni-TYB4gJ0D0ArwzuV9k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need `this.x += Math.sin(this.angle) * speed` and `this.y += Math.cos(this.angle) * speed`

Comment: i tried that, but because of the weird placement of the x/y thing, the x/y axis move with the rotation of the game sprite. i need it to be able to rotate and still move up, but because points are constantly changing, it keeps going to wieerd places.

Comment: Here's live code: https://jsfiddle.net/wdc12pjf/ (click "Run", click inside the bottom right part, then use arrow keys)

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. the code there is what is happening, and I DONT want that to happen. i made an example for better understanding. https://example.octopuscat.repl.co

Comment: what i want to happen is when the up arrow is pressed the race track move up, NOT forward. i mean up as in relative to the x/y axis and not relitive to the race track. the race track x/y axis for the traxk are skewed when it turns and are relitive to the track, not the canvas/screen (see example picture). this gives the illusion the red square is moving when it really is not, and is a core piece to my game.